# What happens if a running executable can no longer load its code/data pages?

Tags: executable, virtual-memory

This is under the assumption that the binary is large enough that not all pages were loaded into memory at the start of execution. What would happen if the underlying file system suddenly disappears (e.g. a flakey NFS connection) and the binary jumps to a new code path that requires loading additional pages? The OS would presumably hit a page fault, try to load the binary's page and fail... Then what? Seg fault? Wait and try again later?

Comment: Might be a very long wait when a NFS hard mount goes away ...........